# IE doesn't align my text correctly

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, alignment

I checked this website on Firefox and Chrome and the alignment in the "Releases" section looks correct: http://www.mysecretathens.gr/Sera/releases.html

But if you open the page in Internet Explorer for some reason some of the text, as you can see, is aligned in the center. I have been struggling with this and can't find the solution.

I was wondering if the pseudo elements I was using in the table formats was causing the problem

```
table td:nth-child(even) {text-align:center; }
```

but I think this isn't the case. Any ideas?

Comment: Which version of IE? Anything less than IE9 doesn't support pseudo-selectors like `nth-child`

Comment: I see. But the main problem remains the text alignement, which doesnt work even in IE9, which I have now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your navigation anchors are floated - where is your clearing done to maintain a block like structure? This is why your navigation is broken in IE 7.

I don't think IE 7 supports nth-child in CSS - you may have to do this through Jquery or add a class on the table cell you want the content to be centred.

Hope this helps

Filth

/*****UPDATED ANSWER HERE ********/

I think it's worth you reading up on "**Clearing**" floated elements [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_clear.asp)

Since IE 7 and 6 are a complete B&#@H at times you have to be able to develop what you want in other ways to accommodate for these scum like browsers. So, here is a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4BPC3/1/) of what your "**nav**" css and html should look like according to current standards.

Also, I think you need to brush up on knowing when to use an "**id**" as opposed to a "**class**" - 
in this case you will / should only have one "**nav**" within your HTML therefore you want to give this an **ID** as it's unique.

If you want an in-line navigation, I find it's best to float the "**li**" elements and have your clearing done after the navigation by adding the class "**clearfix**" to the "**ul**" and style accordingly.

For a brief example on "**clearing**", I have a div after the nav which contains a paragraph. If you remove the class "**clearfix**" from the "**nav**" you will see the "**paragraph**" appear in-line with the "**nav**" as it should. So this is why it's important to clear all floated elements.

As for your table centring issue, the Jsfiddle I gave you is the route to take as it will accommodate all browsers and mobile devices.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you give an example of the code? What do you mean with navigation anchors? The menu bar?

maybe `{clear:both}` ?

Comment: @a.litis Will edit my answer in an hour or so with code for you to use :-)

Comment: Updated answer above - let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1):

You have malformed html on your page `<center>cover: Poor Designers</></div>` I assume its suppose to be  `<center>cover: Poor Designers</center></div>`. Different browsers will render malformed markup in different ways, chrome threw the `<center>` away and ie wrapped it around a div

Comment: Yeah thought about it also but doesn't matter, have ckecked it. Thanx anyways

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the table that it's inside of is defaulting to text-align center for some reason and that td is inheriting the value.

```
.text table{
    text-align:left;
}
```